# Does Zeitgeist slow performance considerably

Tags: performance, zeitgeist

This was talked to me today and I actually did not have a proper answer, so I was wondering if Zeitgeist had any impact in performance. For example if comparing Ubuntu with and without Zeitgeist in terms of: Memory Usage, CPU Usage and Performance in general.

It is my believe that since Zeitgeist is mostly en Event Logger and not a File Sysyem indexer, the performance would be so low that it would not registered even on an old Pentium 3 when compared, like I said, with an Ubuntu that has Zeitgeist and one that doesn't. Am I right or wrong about this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is right. Zeitgeist itself only takes in events and does now crawl around. Something had to send it events and it just stores it with max 2 SQLite calls ;)

Comment: Hi seif, I was wondering if you could you tell me where you got the 2 SQL calls or are you just calculating it based on the amount of information that is gathered in a single event?

Comment: I am one of the Zeitgeist devs :D

Comment: seif - 'nough said ^^.